# RewriteRule htaccess simply doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying this for hours watching online tutorials and stack overflow questions but it doesn't seem to work at all.

I've enabled rewrite on my wamp server.

**Example URL:**

`http://localhost:8081/WEBSITE_URL/page.php?page=about`

**.htaccess contents:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/(\w+)$ ./page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^page/(\w+)/$ ./page.php?page=$1
```

**Expected URL:**

`http://localhost:8081/WEBSITE_URL/page/about/`

**What comes out as result:**

Absolutely nothing. No errors, or error logs, just same as no .htaccess.

Could anyone point me in right direction?

Comment: Did you allow .htaccess? `AllowOverride All` in the httpd.conf file for the directory directive.

Comment: Yeah .htaccess should be allowed. AllowOverride All is there in httd.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /WEBSITE_URL/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?(page)=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/(\w+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: That is cool, finally I see some changes. It redirects to http://localhost:8081/WEBSITE_URL/page?page=about though, just seems to remove .php from the url.

Comment: Thanks, after trying the edit, it goes to http://localhost:8081/WEBSITE_URL/page/about/?page=about